# How to Bulk Delete in PHP-OpenCloud/OpenStack

Tags: php, swift, openstack, ovh

I've got a problem iam currently building a php backend with connect to an OVH object storage
and I would like to make a bulk delete using the php-opencloud sdk
According to [the documentation](https://php-opencloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/object-store/objects.html#delete-multiple-objects) there is a function named batchDelete() or bulkDelete() which does exactly what i am searching for but when I call it, php throw an error saying the called method does not exist (I have seen in the GitHub that batchDelete is deprecated and we should use instead bulkDelete but none of them work)

```
$openstack
    ->objectStoreV1()
    ->batchDelete($list);

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: OpenStack\ObjectStore\v1\Service::batchDelete is not defined
```

OR

```
$openstack
    ->objectStoreV1()
    ->bulkDelete($list);

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: OpenStack\ObjectStore\v1\Service::bulkDelete is not defined
```

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: After some research have read that RackSapce/php-opencloud and Openstack/php-opencloud are two different framework that have been merged to make Openstack/php-cloud so the bulkDelete option has been deleted for non-Rackspace server
so there is no solution to bulkDelete without a loop in php